Setting ArgoCD templates and triggers with Terraform
I have my helm_release setup as the following:
resource "helm_release" "argocd" {
  namespace  = kubernetes_namespace.argocd.metadata.0.name
  name       = "argocd"
  repository = "https://argoproj.github.io/argo-helm"
  chart      = "argo-cd"
  version    = var.argocd_chart_version
[...]
}

Now I want to add templates and triggers to the chart. I have them in argocd/triggers.yaml and argocd/templates.yaml. Example of triggers.yaml (I have tried both with a trigger. prefix and without):
trigger.on-created: |
  - description: Application is created.
    oncePer: app.metadata.name
    send:
    - app-created
    when: "true"
trigger.on-deleted: |
  - description: Application is deleted.
    oncePer: app.metadata.name
    send:
    - app-deleted
    when: app.metadata.deletionTimestamp != nil

The helm_release set part is as follows:
  set {
    name  = "notifications.triggers"
    value = file("${path.module}/argocd/triggers.yaml")
  }

However, this results in the following error:
│ Error: YAML parse error on argo-cd/templates/argocd-configs/argocd-notifications-cm.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 30: could not find expected ':'
│
│   with module.prod.module.kubernetes.helm_release.argocd,
│   on modules\kubernetes\argocd.tf line 19, in resource "helm_release" "argocd":
│   19: resource "helm_release" "argocd" {

How do I set my triggers and templates correcly using Terraform? Preferably by loading the file but if I need to define then manually that is also doable.

I think you would need to be even more specific, so something like notifications.triggers.trigger.on-created and then pass it the YML file. But not sure if that would work. And maybe in that case have two set blocks, the other one would be for notifications.triggers.trigger.on-deleted.

@MarkoE That can work, but defeats the whole purpose of having them centralized in one YML file. I think I might give up on trying to let the helm chart manage the configmap and just create it myself

Well, if you want to have only one file, then I would probably go with the values argument instead of using set.
